# Verify if link starts with http when using lxml and xpath in Python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to print all the links from multiple pages using the following:

```
my_page = '//div[@class="product_info"]//table//tr[7]//td[2]//a/@href'
```

Now, this works for most of the links, but in some cases I have something like:

`<a href="To follow">To follow</a>` which isn't a link.

How can I omit these links ? What condition should I use when using:

```
# some more code
EMPTY = ''
my_page = '//div[@class="product_info"]//table//tr[7]//td[2]//a/@href'

for part in dom1.xpath(my_page):
    FINAL_URL = urlparse.urljoin(url, part)

    if part == EMPTY:
        continue
    print part
```

Comment: What do you want to do if a link is relative, like `<a href="hello/index.html">`, or if its an anchor `<a href="#toc">Table of Contents</a>`?

Comment: There will be, for sure, a full link like: `http://example.com/something`

Comment: So you are only interested in links that start with `http://`? What about `https://`?

Comment: They can also start with `https://`. That's why I asked for a method to match only the first 4 characters. Any other ideas ?

Comment: So, to clarify - you are only interested in those links that start with `http://` or `https://` and want to ignore the rest.

Comment: Yes, indeed. That's what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter those links that start with `https://` or `http://`, simply add a condition in your loop:

```
# some more code
EMPTY = ''
other_links = set()
processed_links = set()
my_page = '//div[@class="product_info"]//table//tr[7]//td[2]//a/@href'

for part in dom1.xpath(my_page):
    if part[:4] == 'http':
        if part not in processed_links:
            processed_links.add(part)
            FINAL_URL = urlparse.urljoin(url, part)
    else:
        other_links.add(part)
```

I've also added some code so that:

1. You collect all the other links that are not processed.
2. If the same (valid) link appears in the page more than once, you only process it once.

Comment: Can you alse edit your answer so that I will save all the other links somwhere else ?